# Sqlalchemy: automatically calculate the value of a column upon another column changed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want the value of a column (`is_dangerous_token`) to be calculated using a method.
Here is what I have gone so far.

```
class PassRecovery(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'pass_recoveries'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_email_address = Column(Unicode(255), ForeignKey('accounts.email_address'), index=True)
    account = relationship('Account', backref=backref('pass_recoveries', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    _is_dangerous_token = Column('is_dangerous_token', Unicode(255))

    def _set_is_dangerous_token(self, account_email_address):
        secret_key = config.get('is_dangerous_key')
        signer = TimestampSigner(secret_key)
        self._is_dangerous_token = signer.sign(account_email_address)

    def _get_is_dangerous_token(self):
        return self._is_dangerous_token

    is_dangerous_token = synonym(
        '_is_dangerous_token',
        descriptor=property(_get_is_dangerous_token, _set_is_dangerous_token)
    )
```

But the problem is that when I create a row by passing in the email_address, the `is_dangerous_token` is not generated using the code I wrote. The created row only has the `id` and the relation to the `account` and `is_dangerous_token` has no value in the database.
thanks for any help

Comment: As i understood, you want to value of the column is calculated automatically when you constructing a model. is it true ?

Comment: @pylover yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `synonym` on the `account_email_address` column, because you need it's value to generate the token:

```
class PassRecovery(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'pass_recoveries'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    _account_email_address = Column(Unicode(255), ForeignKey('accounts.email_address'), index=True)
    account = relationship('Account', backref=backref('pass_recoveries', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    is_dangerous_token = Column('is_dangerous_token', Unicode(255))

    def _set_account_email_address(self, account_email_address):
        self._account_email_address = account_email_address

        secret_key = config.get('is_dangerous_key')
        signer = TimestampSigner(secret_key)
        self.is_dangerous_token = signer.sign(self._account_email_address)

    def _get_account_email_address(self):
        return self.account_email_address

    account_email_address = synonym(
        '_account_email_address',
        descriptor=property(_get_account_email_address, _set_account_email_address)
    )
```

**EDIT 1**

Assume `Persoan.A` is a synonym.

```
session.query(Person).filter(Person.A > 8)
```

So you can use columns which not exists in database in your query for calculating complex expressions.

But you cannot do this with properties, In your case It's better to simply use python's property instead of synonym, to avoid cost of the sqlalchemy synonym.

Another approach is to use [sqlalchemy events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html), listen for changing the attribute, and do whatever you want when the event is raised.